# Docker VS2017 debug .net Framework application that use custom network

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, docker

Given:

- Visual Studio 2017 15.5.4
- Windows 10
- Docker 17.12.0-ce-win47 (15139)
- .net Framework 4.6.1 console application running in docker container

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\app\\myproject.exe"]
```

When trying to run and debug it with following docker-compose debugging works fine.

```
version: '3'

services:
  myproject:
    image: myproject        
    build:
      context: .\myproject
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

However when I try to introduce custom network either

```
version: '3'

services:
  myproject:
    image: myproject        
    build:
      context: .\myproject
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - bck

networks:
  bck:
    driver: overlay
```

or

```
version: '3'

services:
  myproject:
    image: myproject        
    build:
      context: .\myproject
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - bck
      - default

networks:
  bck:
    driver: overlay
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

I am unable to debug application due to following error:

> The Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be  running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.

Comment: Error message means that Visual Studio could not find the correct instance of the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor on the remote computer. MS official doc has given several trouble shooting ways to resolve the issue according to this error message, please have a check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-the-microsoft-visual-studio-remote-debugging-monitor-msvsmon-exe-does-not-appear-to-be-running-on-the-remote-computer

Comment: unfortunately this article has nothing Docker specific